# Receiving 500 error from soundcloud api only on my ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, soundcloud

I am running a node application which uses the `request` lib to access playlist information from soundcloud. On my local machine, this works without a hitch, but on my ubuntu server it does not. What's more, it was working before and has only recently stopped working. All other HTTP requests leaving my server are executing just fine.

I have heard that this could be due to request limits, but I have specifically constructed my app in such a way that it is only calling to the API once every 5 minutes which is well-below the 15,000 request limit per 24 hours. Additionally, I should probably be receiving a `429` error code if that were the case, as per soundcloud docs

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits#play-requests

The 500 error i'm getting is incredibly non-specific:

```
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
```

Here is what my request looks like:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/<user_id>/tracks?client_id=<my_client_id>&offset=1&order=created_at&created_at={from: 2016/02/22 05:45:31 +0000}
```

where both the `user_id` and the `my_client_id` are correctly populated. If i take the same URL and print it into my web browser ur a `wget` from my local machine, i have no problems.

Comment: what if you use the same `nodejs` code using `nodejs` on your local machine - if that gets the same error, then you've found the problem is with your `nodejs` code

Comment: I have done that as well. My javascript has no issue collecting soundcloud data until it is on this server.

Comment: additionally, i have tried simply executing a `wget` from my server with the same url, and am receiving the same error. From my local, the same wget command correctly responds.

Comment: Did you check if the ip address resolved was the same between your local machine and the server?

Comment: would i do this by pining the soundcloud api from both my local and my remote servers?

Comment: Having the same issue. Running Debian 8.5. It only started happening semi-recently but curl/nodejs code respond with the same 500 error/HTML code response. If I do an AJAX request in my local computer's browser console, it works fine with the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved by Soundcloud internally. Not sure what was causing it.